# Rails and Ruby versions always conflict, and will never be able to bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I git cloned my own repo, when I want to start (rails s), there will be a request to install Rails (sudo apt install ruby-railties), even though I installed it. If I start the installation (gem install rails), there will be a message that the Ruby version is too old:

```
ERROR: Error installing rails:
        There are no versions of activesupport (= 7.0.0) compatible with your Ruby & RubyGems. Maybe try installing an older version of the gem you're looking for?
        activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0. The current ruby ​​version is 2.6.6.146.
```

If I switch to the requested version (rvm use 2.7), the following message will appear when I run rails s:

```
Could not find proper version of railties (6.1.4.1) in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

When I proceed to bundle install, there will be a need to switch the Ruby version:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.7.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.6
```

This is equivalent to going back to the beginning. This stupid loop prevented me from completing the bundle install and thus rails s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup the environment inside your project folder.

`cd yourproject`

Then install Ruby, Rails and Bundler.

---

**Install Ruby v2.7.0**, through Ruby Version Manager (RVM)
https://rvm.io/

```
gpg2 --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB

\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh

rvm install ruby 2.7.0
rvm use 2.7.0
rvm list
```

---

**Install Rails**, through RubyGems https://rubygems.org

(don't use `apt install ruby-railties` )

```
gem install rails
rails --version
```

---

**(re)Install Bundler**

```
gem install bundler

bundle install
```

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me when I updated my Ruby version to the latest 3.2.2, the latest available (presently). Use "rbenv install --l" to check for the latest version.

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build 
rbenv init
eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"  
rbenv install --l 
rbenv install 3.2.2
rbenv global 3.2.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the pg error, you need to change your 'pg' gem to a lower version. Let us see what you have in your gemfile.

Comment: gem 'pg', '~> 1.2.3'

Comment: what rails version are you running?

Comment: I received a message of ```sudo apt install ruby-railties``` when I checked the version of Rails, but it would happen after execution: ```E: Unable to locate package ruby-railties```

Comment: run "gem install rails"

Comment: Then when I reworked the bundle install, the message "Your Ruby version is 2.7.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.6" appeared,

Comment: so I rvm use 2.6.6 1 and bundle install again, and then I encountered the same ```Gem: :Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension```